# Count number of opened Excel Workbooks

Tags: excel, vbscript, vba

I need to know how many Excel files are opened, so in case there are more than two, I can close the last one. How can I get number the of opened files?? I have read Worksbooks.Count... but I´m not getting anything at all. I´m using vbscript code.

I have tried this... but just get the name of the file.

```
Set objExcel = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
Set WB = objExcel.ActiveWorkbook
WScript.Echo "Hello" + WB.Name
WScript.Echo "number of excel" + WB.Count
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just solved!!!
I just needed to get the instance of workbooks correctly:

```
Set objExcel = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
Set WB = objExcel.ActiveWorkbook
Set WBS = objExcel.Workbooks
WScript.Echo  WBS.Count
```

Comment: Does this actually work if you've also opened workbooks manually?

Answer (score 2):

Why the VBA tag if you are using VBScript?

To get the number of Workbooks in an Excel instance simply use this VBA code:

```
MsgBox Workbooks.Count
```

To get the number of instances of Excel open using VBA then refer to this article:

http://excelribbon.tips.net/T009452_Finding_Other_Instances_of_Excel_in_a_Macro.html

Comment: did not realized de vba tag... I´m gonna change it now